# Gmail Signin button is not identified by Selenium in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am executing Selenium/TestNG script for Gmail Login in WindowsXP/IE8. Script enters userid and password correct in that page, but it is not clicking on 'Signin'option in Gmail.

I ran same script in Windows7/IE9, it worked. Same script is also working for Firefox. Please Advise.

Selenium Version: 2.25.0

```
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.*;


public class New_Booking_Inc {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;

    @BeforeTest
    public void Open_IE() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://www.gmail.com";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
    }

    @Test (testName = "Login")
    public void Login() throws Exception {
        //driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("extsc2");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("Passwords");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void Close_IE() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried using By.Name("signIn") If it is also not working, try to use waitforelementpresent command in webdriver and then click the button using id or name.

Comment: You really don't want to try to automate GMail.  It's one of the most complicated apps on the web.  Everybody tries this for their learning path, but it's fraught with tears.

Comment: @HemChe I have tried by identifying element by name but still no luck. I dont know how to use waitforelementpresent, I am new to Selenium. I have tried in someothers' system where script is working fine. What I have identified is, due to resolution 1152x864 (only in my system) it fails. I changed resolution 1024x768 in my system then it worked. I dont know why it is happening in only my system.

Comment: @RossPatterson Application I am working have login page with user id and password. That was not working then i tried in gmail, because it is somewhat similar code.

Comment: @AbdulHameed To execute the selenium scripts, the browser zoom level should be 100% as far as i know. So that could be the issue. Someone, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Thanks @HemChe, It worked now with 100% zoom level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it out
driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

or use different xpath ""

Comment: Thanks @Anand, It is working as per your comment. Click() is also working if my system resolution is 1024x768.

Answer (score 0):

There are some known issues for IE where .click() is not working properly.

Have you try:

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).SendKeys("\n");
```

Comment: Thanks @kkdjfl, It is working as per your comment. Click() is also working if my system resolution is 1024x768.